# Embedding An Object Into An Assembly

Tags: .net, collections, embed

I have the need to embed an object (A Dictionary) in an assembly. The Dictionary  was created and populated within another application. I know I can serialize the dictionary to a file and then embed that file - just wanted to see if there were any preferable methods. I am also unaware if there is a significant performance issue of reading the embedded file and deserializing it. The dictionary has about 30K entries and each value is a simple property with about 10 properties all of primitives types. The .Net Framework I am using is .Net 3.5.

-Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add it to the resources and set it to type **embedded resource**